# Game music doesnt stop in my android game when user press back button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

In my android game when user press back button music is not stopped even when user close the game music still playing. 
This is my main class for game. MediaPlayer mp1 is used to play music.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView{
      Bitmap bmp,pause;
      Bitmap background,kinfe,note1,appleimg,note2;
      Bitmap run1;
      Bitmap run2;
      Bitmap run3;
      Bitmap coin;
      Bitmap exit;

      private SurfaceHolder holder;
      private int x = 0,y=0,z=0,delay=0,getx,gety,sound=1;
      int show=0,sx,sy;
      int cspeed=0,kspeed=0,gameover=0;
      int score=0,health=100,reset=0;
      int pausecount=0,volume,power=0,applerun=0,shieldrun=0;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public GameView(Context context) 
      {
          super(context);

          gameLoopThread = new GameLoop(this);
          holder = getHolder();

             holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
            {
                 //for stoping the game
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                gameLoopThread.getThreadGroup().interrupt();
             }

            @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
            {
                  //for starting the game
                  gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                  gameLoopThread.start();

             }
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,int width, int height) 
                    {
                    }
             });

             //getting the screen size 
          //   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        //  sx = display.getWidth();
        //  sy = display.getHeight();;

             Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
             Point size = new Point();
             display.getSize(size);
             sx = size.x;
             sy = size.y;
            cspeed=sx/2;
            kspeed=sx/2;
            applerun=(3*sx/4);
            shieldrun=sx/8;
          background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cold);
          run1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.run1);
          run2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.run2);
          run3=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.run3);
          coin=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.coin);
          exit=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.exit);
          kinfe=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kinfe);
          note1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.note1);
          pause=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pause);
          appleimg=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.power);
          note2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.note2);

          exit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(exit, 25,25, true);
          pause=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pause, 25,25, true);
          appleimg=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(appleimg, 25,25, true);
          note2=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(note2, sx,sy, true);
          run1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(run1, sx/9,sy/7, true);
          run2=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(run2, sx/9,sy/7, true);
          run3=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(run3, sx/9,sy/7, true);
          coin=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(coin, sx/16,sy/24, true);
          background=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, 2*sx,sy, true);
          //health dec
          note1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(note1, sx,sy, true);

          mp1=MediaPlayer.create(Game.this,R.raw.game);
          jump=MediaPlayer.create(Game.this,R.raw.jump);
          takecoin=MediaPlayer.create(Game.this,R.raw.cointake);
      }

      // on touch method

      @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                show=1;

                getx=(int) event.getX();
                gety=(int) event.getY();
                //exit
                if(getx<25&&gety<25)
                {
                    //high score
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("higher", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("score", score);
                    editor.commit(); 
                    System.exit(0);

                }
                // restart game
                if(getx>91&&gety<25)
                {
                    if(health<=0)
                    {
                        gameLoopThread.setPause(0);
                        health=100;
                        score=0;

                    }
                }
                //pause game
                if((getx>(sx-25)&&gety<25&&pausecount==0))
                {

                    gameLoopThread.setPause(1);
                    mp1.stop();
                    pausecount=1;
                }
                else if(getx>(sx-25)&&gety<25&&pausecount==1)
                {
                    gameLoopThread.setPause(0);
                    mp1.start();
                    pausecount=0;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }


        @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
        @Override
          protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
          {

          //volume 
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("higher", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = pref.edit();
            volume=pref.getInt("vloume", 0);
            if(volume==0)
            {
                sound=0;
            }

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            //background moving
            z=z-10;
            if(z==-sx)
            {
                z=0;
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, z, 0, null);

            }
            else
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(background, z, 0, null);  
            }

            //running player 

                 x+=5;
                 if(x==20)
                 {
                     x=5;
                 }

                  if(show==0)
                  {
                      if(x%2==0)
                      {
                          canvas.drawBitmap(run3, sx/16, 15*sy/18, null);

                      }
                      else 
                      {
                          canvas.drawBitmap(run1, sx/16, 15*sy/18, null);

                      }


                     //kinfe hit
                     if(kspeed==20)
                      {
                          kspeed=sx;
                          health-=25;
                          canvas.drawBitmap(note1, 0, 0, null);
                      }

                     //power take
                     if(applerun==30)
                        {
                          applerun=3*sx;
                          health+=25;
                          canvas.drawBitmap(note2, 0, 0, null);
                        }
                  }
                //power
                     applerun=applerun-10;
                     canvas.drawBitmap(appleimg, applerun, 15*sy/18, null);

                     if(applerun<0)
                     {
                         applerun=3*sx/4;
                     }

                //kinfe
                     kspeed=kspeed-20;
                     canvas.drawBitmap(kinfe, kspeed, 15*sy/18, null);
                     if(kspeed<0)
                     {
                         kspeed=sx;
                     }

                // for jump
                 if(show==1)
                 {
                     if(sound==1)
                     {
                     jump.start();
                     }

                          canvas.drawBitmap(run2, sx/16, 4*sy/7, null);
                          //score
                          if(cspeed<=sx/8&&cspeed>=sx/16)
                          {
                              if(sound==1)
                             {
                                  takecoin.start();

                             }
                              cspeed=sx/2;
                              score+=10;

                          }



                    // jump-hold
                     delay+=1;
                     if(delay==3)
                     {
                     show=0;
                     delay=0;
                     }
                 }

                  //for coins
                  cspeed=cspeed-5;
                    if(cspeed==-sx/2)
                    {
                        cspeed=sx/2;
                        canvas.drawBitmap(coin, cspeed, 3*sy/4, null);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        canvas.drawBitmap(coin, cspeed, 3*sy/4, null);  
                    }




                    //score
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
                        paint.setTextSize(25);
                        paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
                        canvas.drawText("Score :"+score, 3*sx/4, 20, paint);
                    //exit
                        canvas.drawBitmap(exit, 0, 0, null);
                          if(sound==1)
                          {
                          mp1.start();
                          mp1.setLooping(true);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                             mp1.stop();
                          }
                  //health
                    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
                     myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                     myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
                     myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                     myPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
                     paint.setTextSize(25);
                    canvas.drawText("Health :"+health, 0, (sy/8)-5, myPaint);
                    canvas.drawRect(0, sy/8, health, sy/8+10, myPaint);

                  //game over
                    if(health<=0)
                    {
                        gameover=1;
                        mp1.stop();
                        sound=0;

                        //high score
                        editor.putInt("score", score);
                        editor.commit(); 

                        myPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        myPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
                        canvas.drawText("GAME OVER", sx/2, sy/2, myPaint);
                        canvas.drawText("YOUR SCORE : "+score, sx/2, sy/4, myPaint);
                        canvas.drawText("RESTART", 91, 25, myPaint);
                        gameLoopThread.setPause(1);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(background, sx, sy, null);
                    }
                   // restart

                    if(reset==1)
                    {
                        gameLoopThread.setPause(0);
                        health=100;
                        score=0;
                        mp1.start();
                    }

                    canvas.drawBitmap(pause, (sx-25), 0, null);
              }

          }
```

And this is the loop class for game.

```
public class GameLoop extends Thread {

   private GameView view;
   static final long FPS = 10;
   private boolean running = false;
   boolean isPaused;

   public GameLoop(GameView view) {
         this.view = view;
   }

   public void setRunning(boolean run) {

         running = run;
   }

   public void setPause(int i)
   {
       synchronized (view.getHolder()) 
       {


        if(i==0)
        {
            isPaused=false;
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            isPaused = true;
        }
        }
   }


@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@Override

  public void run() {
       long ticksPS = 100;
       long startTime = 0;
       long sleepTime;
          while (running) {
              //pause and resume

            if (isPaused) 
            {
                  try 
                  {
                      this.sleep(50);
                  } 
                  catch (InterruptedException e) 
                  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }
            else
            {
                 Canvas c = null;
                 startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 try {

                        c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();

                        synchronized (view.getHolder()) 
                        {
                            view.onDraw(c);
                        }

                      } 
                 finally 
                 {
                     if (c != null) 
                        {
                            view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }
                 }
               }
                 sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime); 

                 try {

                        if (sleepTime > 0)
                           sleep(sleepTime);
                        else
                           sleep(10);
                    } 
            catch (Exception e) {}
          }
    }}
```

Comment: Looks like you're playing your sound in another thread.  You probably should stop the thread if the user moves off the page.

Comment: How can I do this please help me @RobertHarvey

Comment: The same way you would stop any other thread.  I'm not an android expert; find an event that fires when the user leaves the page, hook it and terminate the thread from there.

Comment: Which sound are you still hearing after the app closes?  Also, threads can be stopped by either interrupting them or setting a flag that kills the loop, like calling setRunning(false) in your code.

Comment: In GameView class mp1 is the name of sound.. @Lo-Tan

Comment: @PravalSharma It would help if you added [logging](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to your code, to help you debug issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution as I put my class GameView extends SurfaceView inside another class Game extends Activity that enables me to use onBackPressed() method .

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    mp1.stop();
    Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Thank you everyone for your best efforts to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need stop the music manually, you can use in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` for call `mp1.stop()`, or in `onBackPressed()`.

or try use:

```
            @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                mp1.stop();
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
```

Comment: I can't use onBackPressed() because my class is extending from SurfaceView not from Activity

Comment: I edited the post, I think that onKeyDown method can help you.

Comment: The keypress check may not work if the user swipe kills the app.  Your best bet may be to override @onFinish in the activity, call a method on game view (like destroy()) and have it stop all sounds and tell your background thread to stop running.

Comment: You should be getting a call to surfaceDestroyed when the user presses the back button, because that destroys the activity which destroys the surface.   I assume you could also do it there.  I just don't know if that's more clean than doing it from onFinish()

Comment: How can I call surfaceDestroyed on back button ?? @Lo-Tan

Comment: onKeyDown is not working problem is still same @SiloéBezerraBispo

Comment: @PravalSharma My main point is surfaceDestroyed will likely get called as a result of the [back button press](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()), because that finishes the activity.  If you are trying to make a game in Android, it helps to have some understanding of the back button and what default activities do as a result, as well as understanding the [Android lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: @Lo-Tan: be careful with `surfaceDestroyed()` -- if you use the power button to blank the screen, you get `onPause()`, but not `surfaceDestroyed()`. It's better to use `onPause()`. cf. https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Comment: @fadden makes sense.  I wouldn't use surfaceDestroyed() either way - but onPause() is definitely the way to go vs finish()

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo Thanks I got the solution I am posting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing `SurfaceView`, and overriding `SurfaceView.onDraw()`, rarely make sense.

Things go more smoothly if you structure your code as an Activity that has-a SurfaceView, because you need to handle `onPause()` and `onResume()`, and work in the handling of the Surface state callbacks.  You need to provide the standard Android lifecycle methods if you want the app to work correctly when switching away and back, turning the device off and on with the power button, and so on.

The overridden `onDraw()` method draws on the View part of the SurfaceView, rather than the Surface, so unless you want an overlay it doesn't make sense.  You may not notice a problem because it only gets called by the View hierarchy when something invalidates the View.  All you need to do is change `onDraw()` to `doDraw()` and remove the `@Override`, so that it's only invoked when you invoke it explicitly.  (If you *do* want to override `onDraw()`, then you should probably be using a [custom view](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), rather than a SurfaceView.)

[This article](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) explains the interaction between the Activity and SurfaceView lifecycles.  [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) provides several examples of SurfaceView code.  For example, the "multi-surface test" provides an example of an Activity using Canvas rendering to a SurfaceView (actually, more than one).

Comment: I tried this but again problem remains same @fadden

Comment: Pause the music in `onPause()`. Resume the music in `onResume()`.